# How to PCB layout WM7230 MEMS digital microphone?

Tags: pcb, ground, layout, microphone

I'm trying to figure out how I'm supposed to get traces to the four internal data pins of the Wolfson WM7230 Digital Microphone part.

[image: WM7230 Bottom Port Digital Mic]

It's got a ground ring that is supposed to have a tight solder seal. You can see from the datasheet recommended PCB pattern, that the four internal pads are completely surrounded by the copper ground ring.

[image: WM7230 Recommended PCB Land Patterns]

I thought it was bad news to put vias in the pads themselves. This thing is a pretty small part; is the intention that I put via's immediately next to the pads?

Tried to find some example layouts with Google, but no luck.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got some advice from the twitterverse:

https://twitter.com/JulianVeisdal/status/564144465225715712

"For parts with perimeter ground ring (E.g.WM7211, WM7210, WM7230), it is not critical to